# Is there a way to disable alert/confirm boxes using chrome extensions for a particular website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make a chrome extension that opens a url that prompts the user to open an external application. The chrome browser prompts the user with a confirm box(OK or Cancel). I want to disable the confirm box **for that website only**(for security reasons) so that it opens the application without it.

Edit: It is not exactly a confirm box. It is box that says, [Cancel] and [Open With external application].

Answer (score 0):

In the page context, you could overwrite `window.confirm` so that it returns `true` immediately, rather than opening the modal:

```js
window.confirm = () => true;

if (confirm('OK?')) {
  console.log('Going...');
}
```

If the confirm modal opens immediately on pageload, make sure to have the extension run at `document_start` so that `confirm` gets overwritten immediately, rather than after a delay.

Comment: I assume OP means [disable chrome to ask for confirmation to open external application](https://superuser.com/questions/1481851/disable-chrome-to-ask-for-confirmation-to-open-external-application-everytime) rather than window.confirm. Still pretty cool

Comment: 1) this will work only in [page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879), 2) extensions use `document_start` spelling with an underscore.

Comment: using whatsapp:// in the matches content_script does not work....is there a way around that

Comment: even if i use "https://api.whatsapp.com/*" in "matches", it does not work. It seems that the 'opening in external application' modal box is different than a normal confirm box.

Comment: @HarshKumarGupta You should've specified that in your question - that's *not* `window.confirm`, that's something that Javascript can't affect